# NitroShare: "Unable to listen on Port 40818"

Tags: router, port-forwarding, nitroshare

I have just installed NitroShare on both Ubuntu and Win10.
I keep getting the error message "Unable to listen on Port 40818" on both machines. So I guess I have to open port 40818 which I assumingly have to do on my router ("Fritz!Box").

However, I seem to not do it right.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: kindly copy and paste the output of `sudo netstat -plunt`

Comment: Hi @ptetteh227, thanks for your reply! I didn get the error message again but I also didnt try to send files again. Will do this later! The output you requested is: https://pastebin.com/Nr93ArVD

Comment: nitroshare needed an unused port on the local machine to bind to. i guess that port was formerly being used by another application.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies! The problem somehow vanished on its own. No clue why...